# Incompatible input_shape in deep learning using keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras

I am starting off my deep learning journey using the IMDB movie review dataset. I am not sure how the training data is loaded and the input_shape is specified.

```
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)
```

If I understand it correctly, there are 25000 reviews from different movies and the words are encoded as list of integers.

```
train_data.shape
(25000,)
```

1. Since each review has different lengths, how is it possible to store such data in a matrix (i.e., 25,000 rows but columns with different lengths)?

   `model = models.Sequential()`

   `model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(10000,)))`

   `model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(16,)))`

   `model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(16,)))`
2. After reshaping the input to (25000,10000) using one-hot encoding, why is the first argument to input_shape not 25000 (number of samples) rather than 10000 since the Dense layer will compute the outputs according to `relu(dot(w, inputs) + b)`?  ==> (25000, 10000) dot (10000, 16) = (25000, 16) Why don't we specify the input_shape as [None, 10000] as in Tensorflow core?

Answer (score 0):

You can pad using keras pad_sequence

```
data = pad_sequences(data, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
```

I recommend you to use an Embedding layer also

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(num_words, 32, input_length=maxlen))
```